# Problems creating a x% fraction of turtles using n-of command

Tags: netlogo

I want x% of turtles, called pholders, to change their choice from a good 1 to a good 2.
The code is as follows:

`ask pholders [ifelse random-float 1 <= probkauf 
[ask (n-of (count pholders with [choice-num = 1] * 0.01) pholders with[choice-num = 1]) [set choice-num 2]]
[ifelse random-float 1 < 0.5[imitation set typeofchoice 1][beratung set typeofchoice 4]]
   ]`

Initially 100% of the pholders chose good 1. The Problem is as follows: When i rise the number of pholders above something between 102 and 108 n-of doesn't calculate a 1%-fraction anymore, it calculates 10%. The higher the number of pholders the bigger the fraction: for 200 pholders the code calculates 60%. When i leave the number of pholders constant and below 108 but change the percentage from 0.01 to 0.02 it calculates something like 55% or 58%. Is the problem probably coming from ask n-of in an ask environment?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The code you have provided is correct syntax and there is no bug. However, there is insufficient information here to work out what's actually going on since it's likely a logic error. What proportion of your pholders have choice-num = 1 before this code? Unless they all have choice-num = 1, then your `n-of` is going to be 0 with 105 pholders because 1% < 1. Try putting in the statement `print count pholders with [choice-num = 1` immediately before and after the code you have provided us. Any if that doesn't help you work out what's wrong, please provide more of the code.

Comment: Hey JenB, thanks. I edited my question and added some more code

Comment: I have identified the problem, see my answer edits. If you specify what you actually want to happen, I can fix your code - is it that you want 1% conversion with a given probability each tick, or is it that you want each pholder to randomly decide whether to convert?

Comment: Hey Jen, I want that every tick with probability <= probkauf each pholder decides to change its good from good 1 to good 2 with a probability of 1% and with a probability >probkauf decides to do something else

Comment: I think below is what you want - complete example so run it as a new NetLogo model to see how it works

Comment: Thanks for your help Jen

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are running the probabilistic code multiple times. Your code has this structure:

```
ask pholders
 [ ifelse random-float 1 <= probkauf
    [ ask (n-of (count pholders with [choice-num = 1] * 0.01) pholders with [choice-num = 1])
      [ set choice-num 2]
    ]
   [ <do something else> ]
 ]
```

If you have 500 pholders, then there will be 500 times that a pholder selects a random number and, if the number is lower than your value probkauf, it instructs a number of pholders with choice-num of 1 to change it to choice-num 2. 500 potential occasions of 1% conversion is why you have so many being converted.

Based on the description in your comments, I think you want this:

```
globals [probkauf]
turtles-own [choice-num]

to setup
  clear-all
  set probkauf 0.5
  create-turtles 1000
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set choice-num 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  update-choices
  tick
end

to update-choices
  ifelse random-float 1 < probkauf
  [ ask turtles with [choice-num = 1]
    [ if random-float 1 < 0.01
      [ set choice-num 2
        set color red
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [ ; whatever happens with other part of probability
  ] 
end
```